# Откуда берется условие args.length >= 2

Tags: java

Делаю практические задания к учебнику Хорсмана и не могу понять, откуда берется условие в операторе `if` `(args.length >= 2)`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.now().withDayOfMonth(1);
    int month;
    if (args.length >= 2) {
        month = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int year = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        date = LocalDate.of(year, month, 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я так понимаю, это Java.

`public static void main(String[] args)` <- "`String[] args`" - это аргументы командной строки.

К примеру, т.к. вы изучаете Java, то хорошим примером послужит компиляция.
Изначально, для компиляции файла `.java` в файл `.class` вам стоит воспользоваться java  компилятором. Он входит в состав **JDK - Java Development Kit**.

Чтобы его вызывать, в командной строке следует написать javac. Но сам по себе компилятор нужен только лишь для преобразования из *человекопонятного* кода в *машиннопонятный*. Поэтому нам нужно явно ему указать, какой файл компилировать. Для этого нужно передать название файла .java как аргумент. 
Как пример названия файла я взял *"Example.java"*

```
javac Example.java
```

В данном случае *"`Example.java`"* является аргументом, который мы передали в программу.

Для этого нужен "`String[] args`"

Если вы изучали уже массивы, то здесь явно указано, что аргументами программы явлется массив строк. И каждая строка, входящая в этот массив может являться определенным аргументом для работы программы. Аргументы для определения конкретного поведения программы. Для четкого понимания этого советую прочитать про [Command Line Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern).

Т.к. в вашу программу передается массив с названием **`args`**, то у него имеется все стандартные поля/поведения массива.

Ну и в вашем случае `args.length` - извлекает количество строк из массива аргументов.

А условие `(args.length >=2)` позволяет понять, что если вы ввели в аргументы вашей программы **более одного** аргумента, значит она будет действовать соответственно. В вашем примере, если аргументов **два или более**, значит, вы, как разработчик данной программы, определили, что ,в таком случае, за первый аргумент отвечает **номер месяца** в календаре, а второй - за **год**. И, соответственно, начинаете парсить эти значения, переводя их из строковых типов в числовые.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 2):

Оно берется из знания программиста о том, с каким ожидаемым количеством параметров должна запускаться программа. Обратите внимание на обращения `args[0]` и `args[1]` внутри блока `if`. Чтобы в этих обращениях не получить ошибку "index out of range", длина массива должна быть как минимум `2`.

---

Вы поняли неправильно. Длина массива это количество параметров в командной строке.

```
program.exe 10 abcd 2.34
```

- `args.length` будет `3`.

Comment: если я правильно понял args.length это количество символов введенных в консоль, но я же ничего не вводил, извиняюсь за тупость

Comment: @КириллМеркулов - в ответе.

Comment: тогда вопрос на засыпку, откуда появились параметры в командной строке?))) никак не могу именно вот это понять

Comment: @КириллМеркулов Я их напечатал.

Comment: я увидел, но не могу понять откуда они взялись, я извиняюсь если со мной тяжело, я только недавно начал программированием интересоваться

Comment: @КириллМеркулов Я же не знаю, как Вы запускаете программу. В опциях проекта есть "Run Parameters" или "Command Line".

Comment: @КириллМеркулов параметры в командной строке появились оттуда, что их ввел тот, кто запускает программу, сам , с клавиатуры ввел. Например, программа в вашем вопросе формирует дату, для этого ей нужны месяц и год. Эти месяц и год указываются при запуске программы параметрами, их пишет тот, кто вызывает программу. Например в командную строку пишем : javac Date.java 04 2020 , здесь 04 и 2020 и есть те параметры (месяц и год) для которых захотел сформировать дату тот, кто запустил эту программу. Он может вызвать эту программу еще раз, с другими папаметрами и получить другую дату

Comment: @pavlofff `javac` - служить для преобразования java кода в байт код, а не для запуска java кода

Comment: @Tsyklop ну да, протупил :) но я не об этом писал вообще то ..

Comment: @pavlofff исчерпывающе, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Можно вызвать с помощью `ALT + SHIFT + F10`.

Ввод аргументов через пробел.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]